# Package Rename Issue FBReader

Tags: android

While renaming the package in android eclipse, I am getting an error W/System.err(10980): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/geometerplus/fbreader/formats/PluginCollection and such errors, I renamed the package in manifest.xml by using refactor->rename. Can anybody tell me what is the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Please mention how you did that.BTW here is rough idea: right click on project select android tools and from there select rename package options.

Comment: Waheed, I have done the same. However, as it contains c and c++ native libraries, the renamed packages are not working.

Comment: Hmm i am not sure not in that case you have do some manual changes.Please go carefully it could waste a lot of time.

Answer (score 0):

There are few reasons why this may occur. Class files are bytecode that Java interprets to execute your program. The following must be checked to ensure proper functioning of the application.

1. Class file located, Exception raised while initializing static blocks.
2. ClassNotFoundException -- .class not found for that referenced class irrespective of whether it is available at compile time or not(i.e base/child class).
3. Class file located, but Exception raised while initializing static variables
4. The error indicates, that something was found at compiletime but not at runtime, maybe you just have to add it to the classpath.
5. Right click on your project and select -> Compile Module, and then re-start the project and it should work again.
6. In eclipse make sure you have the shapes, linepoints and the spaceobjects as entries in the .classpath file.